# Error during composer update/install upon migrating to remote server

Tags: php, git, laravel, composer-php, digital-ocean

The error in question:

> [RuntimeException]
>     Error Output: PHP Warning:  require(/home/admin/web/"webpage"/public_html/test/app/Http/helpers.php): failed to open stream: N
>     o such file or directory in /home/admin/web/"webpage"/public_html/test/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php on line 58
>     PHP Stack trace:
>     PHP   1. {main}() /home/admin/web/"webpage"/public_html/test/artisan:0
>     PHP   2. require() /home/admin/web/"webpage"/public_html/test/artisan:16
>     PHP   3. require() /home/admin/web/"webpage"/public_html/test/bootstrap/autoload.php:17
>     PHP   4. ComposerAutoloaderInit95cd02d44d232a8b8d6e5e52544d8647::getLoader() /home/admin/web/"webpage"/public_html/test/vendor
>     /autoload.php:7
>     PHP   5. composerRequire95cd02d44d232a8b8d6e5e52544d8647() /home/admin/web/"webpage"/public_html/test/vendor/composer/autoload
>     _real.php:49
>     PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required '/home/admin/web/"webpage"/public_html/test/app/Http/helpers.php' (includ
>     e_path='/home/admin/web/"webpage"/public_html/test/vendor/phpunit/php-text-template:/home/admin/web/"webpage"/pub
>     lic_html/test/vendor/phpunit/php-timer:.:/usr/share/pear:/usr/share/php') in /home/admin/web/"webpage"/public_html/test/vendor
>     /composer/autoload_real.php on line 58
>     PHP Stack trace:
>     PHP   1. {main}() /home/admin/web/"webpage"/public_html/test/artisan:0
>     PHP   2. require() /home/admin/web/"webpage"/public_html/test/artisan:16
>     PHP   3. require() /home/admin/web/"webpage"/public_html/test/bootstrap/autoload.php:17
>     PHP   4. ComposerAutoloaderInit95cd02d44d232a8b8d6e5e52544d8647::getLoader() /home/admin/web/"webpage"/public_html/test/vendor
>     /autoload.php:7
>     PHP   5. composerRequire95cd02d44d232a8b8d6e5e52544d8647() /home/admin/web/"webpage"/public_html/test/vendor/composer/autoload
>     _real.php:49

**Background:** Was developing locally, got to the point where I wanted to have a staging site. Set up the staging site on digital ocean (entOS 6.5 x64). I then cloned my git repo into my desired folder - configured vhosts DefaultDirectory to my public path.

A default installation works, composer update/install works. However, with my cloned repository I am getting said error. '/home/admin/web/"webpage"/public_html/test/app/Http/helpers.php' is a file I made with some helper methods I could use in various controllers. It has not caused any problems locally. I can composer update/install locally, without any problems.

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are those literal quotation marks in your file path

> /home/admin/web/"webpage"/public_html/test/app/Http/helpers.php

Or are you just using that to indicate your website name normally goes there?  If the former, I'd consider not doing that as it's pretty weird to have quotes in unix file names, and you may run into problems based on assumptions other people have made.

Regardless -- you have the information you need

> [RuntimeException] Error Output: PHP Warning: require(/home/admin/web/"webpage"/public_html/test/app/Http/helpers.php): failed to open stream: N o such file or directory in /home/admin/web/"webpage"/public_html/test/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php

PHP is telling you it tried to require in a specific file

```
/home/admin/web/"webpage"/public_html/test/app/Http/helpers.php
```

but it could not find it ("failed to open stream").  This means either the file doesn't exist on the computer you're trying to load it from, or PHP can't see it for some reason (try dumping the results of `is_readable('/home/admin/web/"webpage"/public_html/test/app/Http/helpers.php');` to see if PHP thinks it can read the file or not.

Comment: yeah the quotation was to indicate my website normally goes there. i know the file exists because locally it works just fine. it's only happening on the remote server, so my next question would be, if php cannot see the file only on the remote server, why would that be?

Comment: @zillaofthegods Three reasons off the top of my head. Because the file's not there (really -- check.  Check HARD.  Try to see the file from a PHP script).  Because the file has the wrong permissions.  Because the remote server is a case sensitive system and you're using a case insensitive system) (helper vs. Helper)

Comment: Ok so it turns out that locally, my system was case insensitive, and as a result, autoload_real.php was reading things just fine. However the linux system I'm working with is case sensitive. `Helpers.php` is uppercase, and autoload_real.php is looking for `helpers.php`. So I either need to make my linux system case insensitive (don't think this is possible)...not sure of the appropriate solution...

Comment: @zillaofthegods Sounds like you need to regenerate your composer autoloader files on the production server -- if Composer's autoloader is looking for a lowercase file it usually means the classmap or include autoloader was used.  Also -- I'd seriously consider using the Laravel and PHP standard of `Helpers.php` for your class file name, and making the class inside PSR-4 compliant.  You'll be a lot happier and run into these problems less.  Also of possible interest -- my in depth series on how autoloading works in modern PHP/Laravel http://alanstorm.com/category/laravel#autoloading

Comment: it is currently 'Helpers.php'. how do I regenerate the autoloader? Thanks a lot, I'll check out your series :p.  I tried `composer dump-autoload`, this did not work

Comment: @zillaofthegods Last one for free -- are you refereing to the class as "helpers" instead of Helpers in code? (Maybe research some of this yourself and come back with a better question.  There's too many factors in play for me to give you a "right" answer) Good luck!